# How to prevent queue items lost if application will shutdown unexpectedly?

Tags: c#, queue, task

I've implemented queue with dedicated thread in my application.

I'm worring about keeping items in queue.
What if for some reason this application will close unexpectedly right in time when new items are adding in queue?
As i understand the dedicated thread isn't guarantie working after application closing. The process might be shutdown.

So should i save item to file every time it enqueue and then remove after item is processed? Or it's better to use some separated application or self-hosted task?

EDIT:
It is WinForms application with using System.Collections.Generic.Queue

Comment: You haven't mentioned which queue technology you are using, but any worth using have durability features built in.

Comment: @Crowcoder it is System.Collections.Generic.Queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally to keep your queue persistent - you have to use some kind of storage. Keeping the data in memory would not prevent you from data loss.

The easiest way to keep it reliable - to use some in-built cloud solutions like [Azure Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions)/ [Azure Queue Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues?tabs=dotnet), [Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html), etc.

If you are building the system yourself - you can use DB or even a file storage.

Comment: How do you think what will be more useful to multi-thread enqueue: files, DB or MSMQ?
As i understand MSMQ using storage files so this is only a useful wrapper to work with files. Am i correct?